# How do you measure the 'explained variance' of arbitrary linear embeddings?

Tags: statistics, variance, principal-component-analysis

**Question Elaboration:**
When I say 'linear embeddings' I mean a lower-dimensional representation of variables resulting from an arbitrary linear transformation. And when I say 'explained variance' I mean in the sense that 'explained variance' is measured for PCA's principal components.

**Context of Confusion:**
I realized I'm confused about exactly what this means because while on the surface the idea of 'explained variance' from lower-dimensional encodings makes sense. *I've come to wonder if rigorously speaking it is at all possible for anything but a model to 'explain variance' of original variables (i.e. R^2 measure)*...

**Attempt 1 to draw connection to PCA:**
For example [This website](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-12-11-pca-explained-variance) says that total variance for PCA is sum of individual variances of the PCA variables, and then explained variance for each PC is portion of that total variance present in a PC. I don't see how this could generalize to arbitrary lower dimensional representations because you could just scale some of the lower dimensional variables arbitrarily and change which represent more of the variance no?

**Attempt 2 to draw connection to PCA:**
I've also seen on numerous websites (e.g. [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/seminars/efa-spss/)) that the explained variance for a PCA variable is the corresponding eigen-value but I'm not sure what the analogue to arbitrary lower-dimensional linear representations would be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right that the notion of "explained variance" does not make very much sense without some kind of inverse mapping from the embedding back into the original space. I suggest fitting a linear regression model $y_i\sim \beta x_i$ where $y_i$ are the original points and $x_i$ are the corresponding lower-dimensional embedding points. Then you can compare the variance of $y_i$ to the variance of the predictions $\beta x_i$.

Note that if the points $x_i$ are obtained through PCA, then $\beta$ ends up being the transpose of the projection map, and you recover the normal formulas for variance explained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had considered this too but then I became concerned about the justification for using the linear model. It seemed reasonable given the original mapping was linear, but I had a lingering doubt about whether in this context 'explained variance' should be measured by the *best possible inverse mapping* (e.g. non-linear). And then this raised a whole host of other uncertainties that I didn't know how to resolve rigorously.

Comment: What do you think? Does this matter? Or is a linear model reasonable given that the original transformation was linear?

Comment: @profPlum defining the variance using the best possible inverse mapping is surely too flexible. consider that you will only have finitely many data points, but the space of all possible non-linear mappings is infinite dimensional. similarly, there will always exists *some* mapping that perfectly carries each embedding point to the corresponding original point.

Comment: at any rate, I have mainly seen the concept of explained variance show up in the context of linear regressions, ANOVA, etc. I am not sure that it is such a natural thing to consider for non-linear models.

Comment: Ya I think you're right. I'm accepting your answer